# Does having NTFS partitions between my ext4 and linux-swap partitions create any issues in the future?

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, ntfs

Partitions in my PC:-

1. /dev/sda1 - FAT32 - /boot/efi - 512 MB - boot
2. /dev/sda2 - ext4 - / - 244.14 GB
3. /dev/sda4 - NTFS - 312.50 GB - msftdata
4. /dev/sda5 - NTFS - 370.44 GB - msftdata
5. /dev/sda3 - linux-swap - 3.93 GB

I created the two NTFS partitions after installing **Ubuntu 14.04.01 LTS** on my laptop. For the time being, everything is working fine and I haven't yet used the NTFS partitions. Can these lead to any future issues or is it ok if I keep it like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As summarized by [Bufeu on the Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2116550):

> NTFS is a a proprietary file system. It works fine in my servers find it useful for some applications at times. Everything that ntfs-3g can do was achieved by reverse engineering. The NTFS support in Linux(Ubuntu) should be stable. But one of the down sides of NTFS is that it doesn't support Linux file permissions, so this must be set when mounting the partition: 
>   http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1604251

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had gotten worried for a while.

Comment: Glad that it helped you!

Comment: The last sentence is not quite correct. NTFS is POSIX-compliant and has ACLs so [Linux definitely can use those for permissions](http://jp-andre.pagesperso-orange.fr/permissions.html) with some plug-in. However most current implementations don't use those bits and set permission directly while mounting